# Sending Email with Attachment Failed(Using System.Net.Mail) without Attachment working

Tags: vb.net, email, email-attachments

I have successfully sent email using my code below:

```
   Friend Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Try
         Dim Smtp_Server As SmtpClient
         Dim e_mail As MailMessage
         Smtp_Server = New SmtpClient()
         Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
         Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("myuserid@gmail.com", "mypassword")
         Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
         Smtp_Server.Port = 587
         Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

         e_mail = New MailMessage()
         e_mail.From = New MailAddress(txtFrom.Text)
         e_mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text)
         e_mail.Subject = "Email Sending Subject"
         e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
         e_mail.Body = txtMessage.Text  ''Take from textbox

         attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment("D:\mypdfdoc.pdf")
         e_mail.Attachments.Add(attachment) 'attachment
         Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
         MsgBox("Mail Sent")

      Catch error_t As Exception
         MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
      End Try
   End Sub
```

But when I attached a file with:

```
attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment("D:\mypdfdoc.pdf")
             e_mail.Attachments.Add(attachment) 'attachment
```

It throws a error:
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out. at
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

(Without attachment it works fine by enabling less secure apps from google account)
What sort of solution is available yet.

Comment: Whats the size of the file? Most mail systems often arbitrarily limit the size their users are allowed to submit, Gmail is one of them. Have you tried just a small txt file or something?

Comment: It works with small txt files, but I was loading a 7MB pdf file. And couldn't figure out why time was out to attach desired file... any idea?

Comment: So why it was being fail to load a 7MB file while loading txt files successfully?

Comment: Ok, GMail current size is MAX at 25MB, unless you use the Drive API which is up to 10GB... IMHO set a timeout value on the SmtpClient, for example: `Smtp_Server.TimeOut = 500000 `... that will give you a little over 8 minutes. The default value is 100,000 (100 seconds) which its probably taking longer to attach and send.

Comment: Tried with 3MB pdf file with increased timeout it worked. Perhaps it is due to slow connection uploading takes much time...

Comment: Sometimes it can time out if the file youattach is still in use by other processes. For instance, if you want to send a word file which you have currently opened in Word, you might fail because the file is in use.